# Can any infinite dimensional Hilbert space have countably infinite dimension?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Can any infinite dimensional Hilbert space have countably infinite dimension?

I know that there doesn't exist any infinite dimensional Banach space whose dimension is countably infinite for otherwise it would violate Baire's category theorem. What about infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces? Since Hilbert spaces are also Banach spaces the same result has to be true for Hilbert spaces. Isn't it so? Am I missing something?

Any suggestion regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is so. You are missing nothing !

Comment: @Fred I recently came across a problem which states that "Let $\{e_n \}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space $H$ and $P_n$ the orthogonal projection onto $\text {span}\ \{e_1,e_2, \cdots ,e_n\},\ n \geq 1.$ Prove that for all bounded linear operator $T: \mathcal H \longrightarrow \mathcal H$ and $h \in H,$ $P_nTP_nh \to Th$ as $n \to \infty.$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct. But note that we are talking about a Hamel basis here. Every Hilbert space also has a more useful notion of basis, called orthonormal basis, which is a set of orthonormal elements in the Hilbert space with dense span. Such a basis can be countable, for example $l^2(\Bbb{N})$ has orthonormal basis the Dirac functions on the natural numbers.

Comment: I haven't found it anywhere in the book **Functional Analysis** by Walter Rudin. Can you please share me some references?

Comment: From my knowledge of vector space I know that if $\mathcal B$ is a basis of an infinite dimensional $K$-vector space $V$ then every element of $V$ can be written as a finite $K$-linear combinations of vectors in $\mathcal B.$ Is it wrong then?

Comment: Here are some references from the top of my head: Axler's measure theory, Folland's real analysis, Conway's functional analysis. Probably Rudin's book real and complex analysis has it also.  The difference is that with an orthonormal basis you need limits of finite sums.

Comment: @Anacardium Is something still unclear?

Comment: Do you want your answer to be accepted for getting a benefit of 10 reputation points?

Comment: More importantly, accepting an answer removes the question from the list of questions that still need an answer, so it's a way to let the community know that your problem is solved. But I will not deny that I like some reputation points :) So, is everything clear or can I clarify something to you?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me as to why the concept of infinite linear span came in the context of Hilbert space. Unless I read those texts recommended by you it will not be clear to me as to why such thing actually works. That's the reason why I didn't accept your answer. My policy is not to accept any answer unless I can understand each and every single word of it. But if you still want your answer to be accepted I am ready to press the accept button. Please let me know what you wish at the earliest without any hesitation. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Decomposing vectors w.r.t. an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space gives very useful information. This is the entire idea behind Fourier transformation, to name one application.